# Refreshing question doesn't update answers count

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

When pulling down to refresh a question updates the answers count in the top navigation bar see `Answers(2)`. However the navigation bar a little further down the page does not update see
`0 answers >`. See image below, The image has been edit to fit both navigation elements into one screenshot.

Anyone else had this issue or just me?

[image: Navigation items]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for being so observant!

This will be fixed in version **0.1.57**.